# After how much time "IDLE TIME", as seen from cmd "quser" changes from value "none" on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

As in the topic. I found info online that it's supposed to be 1 minute precise, and it ought to start counting after one minute too, but when I checked it with batch script:

```
@ echo off
timeout 130
quser 
timeout 6666
```

after 130 seconds its value was still "none"...

Comment: Are you on Windows Server? If not, then this command is only partially functional.

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10 Edu Edition. In the end, I just implemented what I wanted in Python, but I would still want to learn why "quser" is only partially functional on anything except Windows Server.